# Spark: querying Mongodb with Stratio and RDD

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, stratio

I am querying MongoDB with Spark using Stratio (0.11.). I am interested to use RDDs (no DataFrame).

What I am doing right now is:

```scala
val mongoRDD = new MongodbRDD(sqlContext, readConfig, new MongodbPartitioner(readConfig))
mongoRDD.foreach(println)
```

and it displays the collection content in a correct way.

Is there a way to use a query (as `String` or built via `QueryBuilder`) with Stratio (in my case the query is $near type) to apply to `MongodbRDD`?

Comment: At the first glance it doesn't look like it. It pushes SQL predicates down but its not something that can be used for `$near`.

Comment: Still you can try to use this directly: https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB/blob/231e1fcb961868963bf7efcae04778d5a9c11f78/spark-mongodb/src/main/scala/com/stratio/datasource/mongodb/rdd/MongodbRDD.scala#L37

Comment: yes I was looking at "Filter" although the only thing can work is building with "EqualTo" all the query. Bit strange.

Comment: Have you though about creating a feature request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @zero323 has hinted, the way to do that is using `filters` parameter. These filters are checked by the library and matched against the MongoDB QueryBuilder available filters.

From Spark-MongoDB [source code](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB/blob/8ba860acb297e649ac8d96bbe5d7bd86e23857b8/spark-mongodb/src/main/scala/com/stratio/datasource/mongodb/reader/MongodbReader.scala#L130):

```scala
sFilters.foreach {
    case EqualTo(attribute, value) =>
      queryBuilder.put(attribute).is(checkObjectID(attribute, value))
    case GreaterThan(attribute, value) =>
      queryBuilder.put(attribute).greaterThan(checkObjectID(attribute, value))
    case GreaterThanOrEqual(attribute, value) =>
      queryBuilder.put(attribute).greaterThanEquals(checkObjectID(attribute, value))
    case In(attribute, values) =>
      queryBuilder.put(attribute).in(values.map(value => checkObjectID(attribute, value)))
    case LessThan(attribute, value) =>
      queryBuilder.put(attribute).lessThan(checkObjectID(attribute, value))
    case LessThanOrEqual(attribute, value) =>
      queryBuilder.put(attribute).lessThanEquals(checkObjectID(attribute, value))
    case IsNull(attribute) =>
      queryBuilder.put(attribute).is(null)
    case IsNotNull(attribute) =>
      queryBuilder.put(attribute).notEquals(null)
    case And(leftFilter, rightFilter) if !parentFilterIsNot =>
      queryBuilder.and(filtersToDBObject(Array(leftFilter)), filtersToDBObject(Array(rightFilter)))
    case Or(leftFilter, rightFilter)  if !parentFilterIsNot =>
      queryBuilder.or(filtersToDBObject(Array(leftFilter)), filtersToDBObject(Array(rightFilter)))
    case StringStartsWith(attribute, value) if !parentFilterIsNot =>
      queryBuilder.put(attribute).regex(Pattern.compile("^" + value + ".*$"))
    case StringEndsWith(attribute, value) if !parentFilterIsNot =>
      queryBuilder.put(attribute).regex(Pattern.compile("^.*" + value + "$"))
    case StringContains(attribute, value) if !parentFilterIsNot =>
      queryBuilder.put(attribute).regex(Pattern.compile(".*" + value + ".*"))
    case Not(filter) =>
      filtersToDBObject(Array(filter), true)
  }
```

As you can see, `near` is not being applied but it seems like it could be easily added to the connector functionality since `QueryBuilder` [offers methods to use that MongoDB function](https://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html#near(double,%20double)).

You can try to modify the connector. However I'll try to implement it and make a PR in the following days.

**EDIT:**

A [PR has been opened](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB/pull/100) including a source filter type which describes `$near` so you can use `MongodbRdd` as:

```scala
val mongoRDD = new MongodbRDD(
    sqlContext,
    readConfig,
    new MongodbPartitioner(readConfig),
    filters = FilterSection(Array(Near("x", 3.0, 4.0))))
)
```

Comment: Yes I have already looked at that part of code from GitHub. The ideal it would be just having a "setQuery" method where it is possible to pass the query that you generate normally with QueryBuilder or text String.

Comment: @Randomize That's feasible. However, its quite a lot easier to add `near` filter

Comment: yes I am agree (although there are different type of near queries). BTW the abstraction they are using is coupling the code to a specific version of mongodb-java-driver as QueryBuilder has changed already API once from 2.* to 3.*.

Comment: @Randomize Spark-Mongodb is using casbah 2.8.0 which is the dependency determining the mongodb-java-driver. I've checked and 3.x interface keeps  `near` methods as they were and also adds `nearSpehere`

Comment: Yes thanks. I have changed locally the code then I will pull the request on github.

Comment: @Randomize Check my edit, you might find it useful to pull the referenced PR

Comment: @Randomize It build now :) Thanks for the feedback